# Run mplayer command in background replace &1 with 1

Tags: bash, background, mplayer

The formal way to run mplayer in background.

```
mplayer some.mkv </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
[3]9536
```

`[3]9536` means pid of the mplayer command is 9536.
If i  replace &1 with 1 for the above command:

```
mplayer some.mkv </dev/null >/dev/null 2>1 &
[4] 9590
[3]   Done                    mplayer some.mkv < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> 1
```

Why got the extra output here?

```
[3]   Done                    mplayer some.mkv < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to your change. This happened because your previous `mplayer` instance exited in the mean time. Here's another example:

```
$ sleep 1 &
[1] 18155                                   # Sleep #1 started in background
$ sleep 1 &
[2] 18163                                   # Sleep #2 started in background
[1]   Done                    sleep 1       # Sleep #1 finished because it's been a second
```

Replacing `2>&1` with `2>1` makes mplayer status and errors go to a file named `1` in the current directory. I don't know why you would do such a thing, but bash is happy to oblige.